# Kafka Connect and Hive -> Merge

Tags: apache-kafka, hive, apache-kafka-connect

Given the Hive's features of ACID incremental rollup Merge, I'm trying to understand if:

- Hive Lenses sink: https://docs.lenses.io/5.0/integrations/connectors/stream-reactor/sinks/hivesinkconnector/
- Confluent Hadoop Sink: https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-hdfs/current/overview.html

can apply the incremental rollups as well. I wasn't able to find documentation about their nature of being pure APPEND-ONLY or having also rollups.

The rollup update seems a pretty common problem that I would expect opensource tools of the Kafka Connect family to have addressed.

Comment: Have you tried running either one? Based on my experience with the Confluent one, it is definitely append only, and the Hive integration is not perfect as it seems bolted-on.